# SeekBar move/drag not working

Tags: android, listview, seekbar

I have a (custom) `SeekBar` nested in `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` which is shown as the item of a `ListView`. Now as soon as I'm updating a `TextView` (via `setText`) in  `onProgressChanged` I'm receiving an `ACTION_CANCEL` and my move/drag on the `SeekBar` is canceled. Works fine if not updating the `TextView`.

Any idea what's the problem?

Contents of `layout.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>

            <TextView />

            <SeekBar />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code in custom `SeekBar`:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser) {
        mProgressTextView.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
    }
}
```

By the way: The problem only occurs on Android 6. Works fine on prvious versions.

Comment: can you put your code

Comment: have you override your progress parameter with multiple and divide by increamentProgressBy value. Like as progress = progress / increamentProgressBy ;

Comment: Kind of. The purpose of this SeekBar is to select a temperature between 16 and 28 degrees in steps of .5 degrees. So the value/progress of the SeekBar is in [0, 12] which is mapped to the temperature and shown in the TextView. The progress itself isn't manipulated

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but I also had a problem with a `SeekBar` in a `ListView` receiving a `MotionEvent` `ACTION_CANCEL` when moving and arriving on a step of the `SeekBar` without releasing the touch.

The problem was that I changed some data and called `notifyDataSetChanged` on the list adapter each time the `SeekBar` called `onProgressChanged`.

SOLUTION : avoid calling `notifyDataSetChanged` in `onProgressChanged`, change your data and call `notifyDataSetChanged` in the function `onStopTrackingTouch` of your `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener`.

NOTE : in my list adapter I also change the text of a `TextView` in each call of `onProgressChanged` and it doesn't cause any problems.